# Convert a flat list of points to two dimensional System.Array type Array[Array[Point]] in Python

Tags: python, arrays, ironpython

I am working with Surfaces in Python. I am trying to make a NurbsSurface from a list of control points. However, original data that is available to me is in flat list. Since in order to create a surface i need to convert that data to Array[Array[Point]] which is a type in Systems class. Since I am in Python my original thought was to create a list of lists, but unfortunately that was rejected. Error states explicitly that it only accepts Array[Array[Point]] - a two dimensional array.

```
dsControlPoints = [pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, pt6, pt7, pt8, pt8, pt9, pt10]
uCount = 2
```

I tried taking that and converting to a list of lists since i know the number of points in U and V directions.

```
newControlPoints = [dsControlPoints[i:i+uCount] for i  in range(0, len(dsControlPoints), uCount)]
```

that gives me a list of lists consisting of two points each:

```
newControlPoints = [[pt1, pt2], [pt3, pt4], [pt5, pt6], [pt7, pt8], [pt9, pt10]]
```

I am not sure what would be easier to either go from flat list or from this list of lists. I found that in order to create a System.Array i need to call a:

```
Array.CreateInstance([Point], (5,2))
```

but that creates an empty array and I have no clue how to populate it. I thought that i could just convert an existing list of lists to an array and append them together into another array but there is no such thing as append that i can call on array nor there is Array.Add that works in IronPython 2.7 which is what I am using.

How can i convert either the flat list or the list of lists to a two dimensional Array[Array[Point]] which is a System.Array type and not a Python type.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're using IronPython. A 2-d array could be created like this:

```
from System import Array
array = Array[Array[int]]( ( (1,2), (3,4) ) )
```

For more information, please read this document: http://www.ironpython.info/index.php?title=Typed_Arrays_in_IronPython

Comment: Timothy, I did read this post but it doesn't explain anything about populating that array from a list of values. Also, i did say that I am using IronPython. This answers nothing. I am sorry that I wasn't clear enough with my question.

Comment: System.Array is a fixed-length data structure. If you want to add/remove elements, use System.Collections.ArrayList instead.

Comment: I am not looking to "add" data, more so to "populate" it from a list of lists. Here's an example that i am trying now: controlPointsArrayArray = Array.CreateInstance(Point, uCount, vCount)
   for i in range(0, uCount, 1):
    for j in range(0, vCount, 1):
     controlPointsArrayArray[i,j] = newControlPoints[i][j]

Comment: problem is that it returns a Array[Point] instead of Array[Array[Point]] so I am making a two dimensional array instead of Array of Arrays...i really need to do array = Array[Array[Point]](((),())) but have no clue how to populate it.

Comment: Try `array = Array[Array[Point]]( map(tuple,newControlPoints) )`?

Comment: This worked like a charm! Can you explain to me what you did exactly? I know what map does but why (touple, list)? i dont get that part. Thank you!

Comment: newControlPoints is a list of list `[[pt1,pt2],...]`, but Array[Array[Point]] expected a list of tuple `[(pt1,pt2),...]`, `tuple()` is a built-in function, which converts a list/str to a tuple.

Comment: so if i had just a flat list would this work: array = Array[Array[Point]](newControlPoints) ?